# adding css class to shopify customer filter area customer_register_link

Tags: shopify

I'm creating a link to the account/register via the `{{ 'Register' | customer_register_link }}` filter, I would like to add a css class to the link that is generated so the generated link is:

`<a href="/account/register" class="btn">Register</a>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to add a CSS class directly to the anchor tag created by the `customer_register_link` filter. The way I would do it is to surround the customer register link in a div like this:

```
<div class="customer-links">
    ...
    {{ 'Register' | customer_register_link }} 
    ...
</div>
```

And apply CSS to the anchor tag like so:

```
.btn, .customer-links a { ... }
```

Also see [this tutorial](http://www.tetchi.ca/shopify-theme-from-scratch-part-12/).

Comment: I thought I saw it being done on other tags but I couldn't find the documentation so maybe I'm just confused.

Comment: [img_tag](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/filters/img-tag) is the only filter I can think of that lets you add a class. Perhaps that's the one you've seen before.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the replace filter and you know the markup will contain `href` so you can use that to add the class.

```
{{ 'Register' | customer_register_link | replace: 'href', 'class="btn" href'}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could, of course, create the link manually. There is a small chance that in the future Shopify will change the registration URL, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the variable  value in particular attribute and replace code

```
<li>{{ link.title | link_to: link.url }}</li>
by this 
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{{link.url }}">{{ link.title }}</a></li>
```